# Django development - how to access model results correctly

Tags: php, django, codeigniter

Ok forgive me if this is a bit of a noddy question but i can't find a example online. I'm a PHP dev converting to Django from Codeigniter. I'm calling a model i have made like thus;

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    for e in Ratecard.objects.filter(reportSuite=region):
        suite = e.reportSuite
        RP_UniqueUsers = e.RP_UniqueUsers
        RP_PageImpressions = e.RP_PageImpressions
        RP_TimeSpent = e.RP_TimeSpent
        RP_PageViewPerVisit = e.RP_PageViewPerVisit
        HP_PageImpressions = e.HP_PageImpressions
        HP_UniqueUsers = e.HP_UniqueUsers
        HP_TimeSpent = e.HP_TimeSpents



return render_to_response('rates.html', locals())
```

In this example 'region' is set from a GET param. My problem is that if i then try to access suite from my template i get nothing out of it. {{ region }} doesn't print any result.

What is the correct way of accessing this data both in the view and in the template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your local view variables are **not** visible in your templates by default. You have to pass them explicitly in a context dictionary. Usually you will do this in [`render_to_response`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render_to_response).

Example:

```
def index(request):
    # a local variable
    region = "sanriku"

    # render_to_response takes a template file name as the first argument
    # and optionally some more parameters, such as a context dictionary,
    # that holds your variables, which will be accessible in this view.
    # Here, e.g. the variable {{ region }} will be accessible and will print 
    # just "sanriku".
    return render_to_response("index.html", {"region" : region})
```

Django 1.3 introduced a new shortcut [`render`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render):

> render() is the same as a call to render_to_response() with a context_instance argument that forces the use of a RequestContext.

A shortcut to any GET request parameter would be:

```
{{ request.GET.q }}
```

if you have a [request context processor](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) enabled.

Just for development purposes: If you want to save some keystrokes during development, you can add all local variables at once via the [`locals()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#locals) function, which *returns a dictionary representing the current local symbol table*. So the most dense way to have access to all local variables in your template as well as all data the *RequestContext* contains, you could write:

```
# Django 1.3
return render("template.html", **locals())

# Pre Django 1.3
return render("template.html", **locals(),
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Yea i had figured out that much so far


updated with my current code, but i get nothing out of the variables...

Comment: Ok, it seems you do not obtain region as a 'standalone' variable. Have you tried `{{ request.GET.region }}` in your view? The `request` object is available in templates, if you have a request context processor enabled (see my edits above).

Comment: Sorry accessing it in the template is only a secondary issue. What i want to know is am i setting the variables correctly in the for loop? and is there a simple debugging method i can use? like var_dump() in php?